# Hard to identify the mobiles from wso2 EMM device management console

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I tried to setup WSO2 EMM V2.0.1 and added few same model Android mobiles to EMM. But I feel hard to identify the mobiles, since all mobiles are showing same information in EMM device management console. I need to select the mobile and jump to specify mobile to see the details(such as IEMI) one by one. The following screen capture which is captured from my testing environment [Capture from testing environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3yEf.jpg). When I search from internet, I watched a demo from youtube and found the console display is different with the my testing environment, the mobile IEMI information is showed on the device management console page and very easy to identify the mobile. The following screen capture is captured from youtube.[Capture from youtube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nnKq.png). May I know any brother have experience about this?

Comment: Capture from youtube is from EMM v110. The Capture from you test environment is EMM v201. We have added this into our road map. As @ycr mentioned you can achieve this with a small customization to render these information too.

Comment: Hi Rasika, May I know if I want to customize the mobile devices showing IMEI in App Store instead of showing DEVICE_NAME, we need to customize <EMM_HOME>\repository\deployment\server\jaggeryapps\store\extensions\assets\mobileapp\themes\store\js\devices.js?

Comment: Bowman Bathiya has already provided the answer. Hope it is clear to you :).

Comment: Hi Rasika, Bhathiya's answer which for the EMM device manangement console and I tried it is worked very well. But the app store "https://localhost:9443/store" customization should not same with device management. Actually, I created another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39248253/how-can-i-use-the-iemi-number-to-identify-the-mobile-in-wso2-app-store-when-i-in for this, hope some brothers have experience on this as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at code and it can be easily customized like this. Here is the diff of `<EMM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/emm/units/device-listing/public/js/device-listing.js`

```
228c228,229
-             { targets: 3, data: 'enrolmentInfo.status', className: 'fade-edge remove-padding-top' ,
---
+             { targets: 3, data: 'deviceIdentifier', className: 'fade-edge remove-padding-top'},
+             { targets: 4, data: 'enrolmentInfo.status', className: 'fade-edge remove-padding-top' ,
247,249c248,250
-             { targets: 4, data: 'type' , className: 'fade-edge remove-padding-top' },
-             { targets: 5, data: 'enrolmentInfo.ownership' , className: 'fade-edge remove-padding-top' },
-             { targets: 6, data: 'enrolmentInfo.status' , className: 'text-right content-fill text-left-on-grid-view no-wrap' ,
---
+             { targets: 5, data: 'type' , className: 'fade-edge remove-padding-top' },
+             { targets: 6, data: 'enrolmentInfo.ownership' , className: 'fade-edge remove-padding-top' },
+             { targets: 7, data: 'enrolmentInfo.status' , className: 'text-right content-fill text-left-on-grid-view no-wrap' ,
263a265
+             var imei = data.deviceIdentifier;
278a281,285
+                         $(this).attr('data-grid-label', "IMEI");
+                         $(this).attr('data-search', imei);
+                         $(this).attr('data-display', imei);
+                         break;
+                     case 4:
283c290
-                     case 4:
---
+                     case 5:
288c295
-                     case 5:
---
+                     case 6:
```

It will look like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe these are two different EMM versions. If you need to show more details you will have to customize EMM. In EMM 2.0.1 same information is already there, you need a small customization to render these information.